# How to trust a self-signed server certificate with the node-opcua client

Tags: ssl, node-opcua

I have a simple node-opcua client and it wants to connect to a server via Basic128Rsa15 policy.

I have created a self-signed certificate and the server does receive this cert and I can move it on the server to the trusted pki directory.

At my client - the node-opcua - I also see a new directory "pki/rejected" with the cert from the server.

My question is now: What do I have to do now so that the client will trust this self-signed cert from the server?

I have already tried to create a "trusted" directory and move it to there, but this does not help, I also have tried to add an option (which I have found via google): serverCertificate=crypto_utils.readCertificate("pki/trusted/04c9f401be19e5a2349460306579c692e777cea5.pem"); But that also didn't help. When I start the client it creates again the cert in the "rejected" folder.

My node-opcua options for the connection:

options:
securityMode: 3                          # None = 1, Sign = 2, SignAndEncrypt = 3
securityPolicy: "http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic128Rsa15"
certificateFile: certificates/cert.pem
privateKeyFile: certificates/key.pem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

version 2.30 onward: node-opcua clients now perform full certificate validation coming from servers:

- if  a server certificate has been generated by a CA, the CA certificate must appear in the PKI of the client ( in the issuer folder) along side with the corresponding CRL.
- by default the client certificate manager accepts valid unknown server certificate for backward compatibility with previous version. This can be reverted by setting the `automaticallyAcceptUnknownCertificates` to false.
- other checks are performed to verify that the certificate of the server strictly complies to the requirements of OPCUA, such as `subjectAltName.uniqueResourceIdentify` must match server's applicationUri, `keyUsage`, key length  etc ...
- if server certificate is known and in rejected folder, client will reject connection with server.

version 2.28 and below: node-opcua clients did not perform server certificate trust/reject checks yet, nor full certificate validation, just basic validate (date, signature ...)

Comment: Hi, thanks, so that means even if the cert is created in the "rejected" directory the client trust the cert. Ok. If true I have another problem connecting to my OPC UA Server...

Comment: @AndreasVogler , you are right your issue might be somewhere else

Comment: I have the same issue, but I use secuirityMode.None. I am confused, that the OPC UA server uses a certificate, although I didnt implement one. 

How can I tell the client to trust the server certificate, even if the the client said "BadCerficateUntrusted"